# Does isomorphism mean "same algebraic structure"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Let $(M_1,+,\times)$ be an algebraic structure, lets say, for example, a ring. If we have another structure $(M_2,+,\times)$ isomorphic to the first one does that mean that $(M_2,+,\times)$ is also a ring ?

Edit : To give more context, in 2 different exercises I had to prove that the following are rings :

1) $(\mathbb{C},+,•)$ where "$+$" is simple addition and $z_1•z_2 = z_1z_2 + \operatorname{Im}(z_1) \operatorname{Im}(z_2)$, where $\operatorname{Im}(z) = $ the imaginary component of z.

2) $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},+,•)$ where $(a,b)+(x,y) = (a+x,b+y)$ and  $(a,b)•(x,y) = (ax,ay+bx)$

In fact, these are the same with different notations:  $x+yi = (x,y)$

Comment: To define what and isomorphism is, you need structure in the domain e codomain beforehand. For example, if you take a ring, and a set with saeme cardinality, you can "reuse" the structure via a bijection, so it would be meaningless.

Comment: I think It depends on the meaning of isomorphism. We say two objects of a category are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism ( invertible morphism) between them. 
 Namely, two isomorphic objects are " the same ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the idea of [*transport of structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure). Lets stick with your example for now. Suppose, we know that $(M_1,+,\times)$ is a ring and we have a set $M_2$ equipped with two operations $\dot+$ and $\dot\times$. Without further investigation we do not know anything else about $(M_2,\dot+,\dot\times)$ rather than being a set equipped with two operations.

Now, suppose we can define a function $f:M_1\to M_2$ which satisfies the following properties

1. $f$ is a *bijection* of sets, saying that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are basically the same set up to renaming
2. $f$ satisfies the *axioms of a ring homomorphism*, i.e. we have $\forall x,y\in M_1$ that
   \begin{align*}
   f(x+y)&=f(x)\dot+f(y)\\
   f(x\times y)&=f(x)\dot\times f(y)
   \end{align*}

Then we can *transport* the given ring structure from $M_1$ to $M_2$ via the function $f:M_1\to M_2$. For example, take the (left) distributive law in $M_2$. Via the surjectivity of $f$ and the ring structure of $M_1$ we may conclude
\begin{align*}
\dot x\dot\times(\dot y\dot+\dot z)&=f(x)\dot\times(f(y)\dot+f(z))\\
&=f(x)\dot\times f(y+z)\\
&=f(x\times (y+z))\\
&=f(x\times y+x\times z)\\
&=f(x\times y)\dot+f(y\times z)\\
&=f(x)\dot\times f(y)\dot+f(y)\dot\times f(z)\\
&=\dot x\dot\times\dot y\dot+\dot x\dot\times\dot z
\end{align*}
In a similiar manner you can in fact prove that all the ring axioms hold in $M_2$ simply by using the properties of the given map $f$ over and over again. I just took the (left) distributive law as an illustration. The [same idea applies when $(M_1,+,\times)$ is a field](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/em1i74/abstract_algebra_isomorphismlike_map_inducing/), or a different algebraic structure defined as a set equipped with operations.

> But $f$ is *not* an isomorphism in the first place! The concept of an isomorphism does not apply in this setting as an isomorphism is commonly defined between objects of the *same* category (as *Maryam Ajorlou* pointed out). In this setting we *use* that we have a bijective, *structure-preserving* map to *transport* (or define) structure from $M_1$ to $M_2$.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes.

It depends on what aspects of the two algebras are isomorphic; for example, $(M_1, +_1)$ could be isomorphic to $(M_2, +_2)$ *as groups*, but not necessarily as, say, *rings* $(M_1, +_1, \times_1)$ and $(M_2, +_2, \times_2)$. If they're isomorphic *as the same structure, including the ring axioms*, then, yes, if one is a ring, so is the other.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is technically correct, but isomorphic doesn't just mean $(M_2,+,\times)$ is a ring, but with the exact same structures. $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be mapped one-to-one on eachother.